# Lagom Framework: Kafka topic not getting created

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, lagom

I am trying to write a small microservice using lagom framework with read side implemented to support mysql.
https://github.com/codingkapoor/lagom-scala-slick

The objective of this service is to expose apis to create, update, and read employees.

Upon execution, however, the project is not creating kafka topic and publishing messages to it. I tried debugging, reading docs and referring couple of other similar projects but no luck so far.

Lagom documentations and similar projects are the only sources that's available to find any help for such fairly newer tech. I really need help to debug and understand this issue. Let me know if this the right platform to ask for such a help.

Steps I take to create an employee and possibly see kafka topic created are as follows:

```
#1. sbt runAll

#2. curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:9000/api/employees \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "id": "128",
    "name": "Shivam",
    "gender": "M",
    "doj": "2017-01-16",
    "pfn": "PFKN110"
}'

#3. /opt/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181

#4. /opt/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic employee --from-beginning
```

Comment: I have run your code, I see topic in kafka.
Could you explain what is not working?

Comment: @VladislavKievski First of all thanks a lot for taking time and effort to help me understand this issue. I have upadted the steps I took to create an employee and see kafka topic created for the same. At step 3 mentioned above, I don't see any topic named "employee" created. Also, I would like to know did you see kafka topic created before initiating curl cmd? Have you setup mysql for this project? What topics are you seeing? 

Let me know if I can explain things better at my end.

Comment: @VladislavKievski I would also like to know if you see data in kafka and mysql "employee" table after you issue curl command to create employee.

Comment: I see kafka topic created after executing curl cmd. No, I remove it, and replace where need to cassnadra, so it will be easier to test for me. I see only one topic. All your events should be stored in the database. Am I answered your question?

Comment: @VladislavKievski This doesn't seem to work for me and I am not sure why? Do you see data in "employee" cass keyspace, if you configured to get created on read side? Could you please post commands and results from kafka and cassandra "employee" keyspace?

Comment: Also, if you can post your code on github as a forked repo or something so that I can refer to see the changes you made, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle I was able to resolve the issue. So basically there were two issues:

1. First issue was because of the order in which the traits `ReadSideJdbcPersistenceComponents` and `WriteSideCassandraPersistenceComponents` are extended to create `EmployeeApplication`. Due to a bug in Lagom the ordering in which you mix in those two traits is relevant and only if you mix in ReadSideJdbcPersistenceComponents before WriteSideCassandraPersistenceComponents you will be able to use this combination.

   Please see this [README](https://github.com/lagom/lagom-samples/tree/1.5.x/mixed-persistence/mixed-persistence-scala-sbt) from lagom-samples.
2. Also, I was not implementing polymorphic event stream properly as explained in the lagom documentation [here](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.5.x/scala/MessageBrokerApi.html#Polymorphic-event-streams).

I have now come up with a working github project which you can refer:
[lagom-scala-slick](https://github.com/codingkapoor/lagom-scala-slick).

Answer (score 1):

Employee service where I added one method *getEmployees*:

```
trait EmployeeService extends Service {

  def addEmployee(): ServiceCall[Employee, Done]

  def getEmployees(): ServiceCall[NotUsed, Vector[Employee]]

  def employeeTopic: Topic[EmployeeAddedEvent]

  override final def descriptor: Descriptor = {
    import Service._

    named("employee")
      .withCalls(
        restCall(Method.POST, "/api/employees", addEmployee _),
        restCall(Method.GET, "/api/employees", getEmployees _)
      )
      .withTopics(
        topic(EmployeeService.TOPIC_NAME, employeeTopic _)
          .addProperty(
            KafkaProperties.partitionKeyStrategy,
            PartitionKeyStrategy[EmployeeAddedEvent](_.id)
          ))
      .withAutoAcl(true)
  }
}
```

In Application config added one line so cassandra settings would look like this:

```
cassandra-journal.keyspace = ${employees.cassandra.keyspace}
cassandra-snapshot-store.keyspace = ${employees.cassandra.keyspace}
lagom.persistence.read-side.cassandra.keyspace = ${employees.cassandra.keyspace}
```

EmployeeApplication looks like this:

```
abstract class EmployeeApplication(context: LagomApplicationContext)
  extends LagomApplication(context)
    with LagomKafkaComponents
    with CassandraPersistenceComponents
    with HikariCPComponents
    with AhcWSComponents {
```

EmployeeServiceImpl added following method:

```
  override def getEmployees(): ServiceCall[NotUsed, Vector[Employee]] = ServiceCall { _ =>
    employeeRepository.getEmployees()
  }
```

EmployeeRepository I rewrite like this:

```
package com.codingkapoor.employee.persistence.read

import java.time.LocalDate

import akka.Done
import com.codingkapoor.employee.api.Employee
import com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.persistence.cassandra.CassandraSession

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

class EmployeeRepository(session: CassandraSession) {

  def createTable: Future[Done] = {
    for {
      r <- session.executeCreateTable("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees(id text, name text, gender text, PRIMARY KEY (id))")
    } yield r
  }

  def getEmployees(): Future[Vector[Employee]] = {
    session.selectAll("SELECT * FROM employees").map(rows =>
      rows.map(r => Employee(
        id = r.getString("id"),
        name = r.getString("name"),
        gender = r.getString("gender"),
        doj = LocalDate.now(),
        pfn = "pfn")).toVector)
  }
}
```

EventProcessor look like this:

```
package com.codingkapoor.employee.persistence.read

import akka.Done
import com.codingkapoor.employee.persistence.write.{EmployeeAdded, EmployeeEvent}
import com.datastax.driver.core.{BoundStatement, PreparedStatement}
import com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.persistence.cassandra.{CassandraReadSide, CassandraSession}
import com.lightbend.lagom.scaladsl.persistence.{AggregateEventTag, EventStreamElement, ReadSideProcessor}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}

class EmployeeEventProcessor(readSide: CassandraReadSide, employeeRepository: EmployeeRepository, session: CassandraSession)
  extends ReadSideProcessor[EmployeeEvent] {

  override def buildHandler(): ReadSideProcessor.ReadSideHandler[EmployeeEvent] =
    readSide
      .builder[EmployeeEvent]("employeeoffset")
      .setGlobalPrepare(() => employeeRepository.createTable)
      .setPrepare(_ => prepare())
      .setEventHandler[EmployeeAdded](processEmployeeAdded)
      .build()

  private val createPromise = Promise[PreparedStatement]

  private def createFuture: Future[PreparedStatement] = createPromise.future

  override def aggregateTags: Set[AggregateEventTag[EmployeeEvent]] = Set(EmployeeEvent.Tag)


  private def prepare(query: String, promise: Promise[PreparedStatement]): Future[Done] = {
    val f = session.prepare(query)
    promise.completeWith(f)
    f.map(_ => Done)
  }

  def prepare(): Future[Done] = {
    for {
      r <- prepare("INSERT INTO employees (id, name, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", createPromise)
    } yield r
  }

  private def processEmployeeAdded(eventElement: EventStreamElement[EmployeeAdded]): Future[List[BoundStatement]] = {
    createFuture.map { ps =>
      val bindCreate = ps.bind()
      bindCreate.setString("id", eventElement.event.id)
      bindCreate.setString("name", eventElement.event.name)
      bindCreate.setString("gender", eventElement.event.gender)

      List(bindCreate)
    }
  }

}
```

I added method *getEmployees* to check that read side is working. Also, after sending create employee you need to wait 10-20 seconds before the employee will be appeared in the database, after that you can get it from readside.

Comment: Your solution looks fine but I still could not figure out the issue with mine. I want to try this project with readside implementd in Jdbc using Slick. However, I would like to bring two important developments in debugging this issue to your notice. #1. I tried to make this project even leaner by getting rid of readside and it seem to work! You can see the changes in a new branch named `noreadside`. Which majorly involves changes to the `EmployeeApplication.scala` besides getting rid of readside. This clearly indicates that the issue is somewhere in classes that I am extending in this class.

Comment: Cont.. #2. I have noticed two warning messages in the `runAll` logs which I am suspecting could lead us to the issue we are trying to debug. I have included them in the post. Please see.